# Select rows in dataset table based on other dataset table

Tags: .net, vb.net, select, dataset

I have a dataset that has two tables in it. I want to do the following (or something like it) is it possible and is how I have it correct?

```
dsTabData.Tables("FilingTabs").Select("fs_ID not in (select fsp_fsid from ParentTabs)")
```

how do you reference data from other table in the same dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok ok before y'all flame me! ;)

I did some more looking around online and found what looks like the stuff I need, now off to read some more from here:

[Navigating a Relationship Between Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6s958d6(VS.80).aspx)